# Вывод фотки из БД на страницу

Tags: php

Вот у меня стоит на сайте "Выбрать файл". Я выбираю JPEG файл. Он заносится в БД как "file_name.jpeg".

Вопрос1:

```
Как мне сделать, чтобы фотка загрузилась в какую то конкретную папку?
```

Вопрос2:

```
Как вывести фотку из БД и отобразить ее на странице? Хотя т.к записывается название файла, и если буду знать в какой папке она находится, то смогу выявить написав весь путь.
```

Вопрос2(2):

```
Как отобразить фотку на странице, зная весь путь файла?
```

Answer (score 1):

Приведу пример.
Запись в базу информации о загруженном файле (сохраняем имя файла и дату загрузки), загрузка файла в директорию upload:

```
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO `files` (`name`, `timeadd`) VALUES ('".$_FILES[file][name]."', '".time(void)."')");
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],"upload/".$_FILES[file][name]);
```

Для отображения фотографии делаешь запрос к базе, получаешь имя и выводишь:

```
<?
$file = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `files` WHERE `id`='$_GET[id]'");
$file = mysql_fetch_array($file);
?>
<img src="upload/<?=$file[name]?>">
```

Answer (score 0):

1. [move_uploaded_file — Перемещает загруженный файл в новое место](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.move-uploaded-file.php)

2,3 - [img](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_img.asp)

Answer (score 0):

Не знаю, вот посмотрите, может поможет такое решение [FancyUpload](http://ajaxs.ru/lesson/ajax/122-fancyupload_massovyj_zagruzchik_fajlov_na_server.html) - массовый загрузчик файлов на сервер